# Button not working as expected

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I facing trouble in my button. When it is clicked, no Toast getting displayed. I have make sure the id is correct.

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "AAA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/monthly_expenses"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="You haven't added any month yet"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_login"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/NoData"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Add Monthly Expenses"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NoData"/>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am pulling my hair out of this! Anyone know what's the problem ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check import for `View.OnClickListener` ?

Comment: @MayurRaval How to check ?

Comment: Are you sure "getApplication()" is the the right context for the button? Try "[ActivityName].this" or perhaps "v.getContext()"

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon my activity is extends to `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @Seng, check with `Toast.makeText(this, "AAA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` or checkk import which is on top of the file

Comment: code working fine at my side in AppCompatActivity

Comment: please provide your activity file and gradle file xml already you have provided

Comment: @YogeshBorhade my problem was fixed. It seems like the relative layout problem.

Comment: @Seng - my suggestion had nothing to do with the ancestry of the Activity. However I copied your code into a new project and it worked fine on my side, no changes.

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon Strange. You use `getApplication()` and it works ?

Comment: @Seng Yes. Keep in mind I used a new project - I did not override application in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/monthly_expenses" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NoData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="You haven&apos;t added any month yet"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_login"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NoData"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Add Monthly Expenses" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

as you have used relative layout and also added listview which fills your whole content because of which below view is not clickable.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild you project. Sometime this might help too.

Answer (score 0):

Change Context

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AAA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed one point. It should be `getApplicationContext()`. I came up with this code which may helpful to you:

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AAA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 });
```